# Present continuous or be going to or will for the far/distant future?

Tags: grammar

**Can we use present continuous for the far future?**

**For example:** *I am building a hobbit house after retirement.* (I am 30 years old now. I have been saving up money for the hobbit house for a while now. I have planned everything and arranged for it. Like I have seen a few places for the house and fixed one)

**One more example:**

*After retirement I am spending time with my family. I am visiting new places and having fun with them.*

**OR**

*After retirement I am going to spend time with my family. I am going to visit new places and have fun with them*

**OR**

*After retirement I will spend time with my family. I will visit new places and have fun with them.*

**Which tense should be used here?** I am a bit confused.
I read about it in **Practical English Usage by Michael Swan (Oxford) entry 39.1.** It says that if the arrangement exists now we use present continuous *(I am seeing Alice on Saturday.)* and if we are not talking about the present then we use simple future i.e. will *(I wonder if she will recognise me.)*

*We are going to get a new car.* (The decision already exists.)
*I hope it will be better than the last one.* (not talking about the present.)

So if I have planned everything for my retirement which is in the far/distant future should I use *present continuous* or *be going to* or *will*?

Comment: Plenty of people think they [***are going to heaven** when they die*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22going+to+heaven+when%22) even though they haven't made *specific* arrangements with St Peter to be let through the pearly gates.

Comment: It doesn't sound natural to me to use the present continuous for something planned for the distant future. Realistically, for a 30-year-old there could have been many changes of circumstances by the time they retire, so most people would say _I plan to_ or _I hope to_.